# How to allow users to choose different theme?

Tags: theming

Some of my site users prefer a light theme, others prefer dark one. In drupal 6, is there a way to allow users to choose their favorite theme? How?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look this up, but if I'm not mistaken, you should enable the themes users can choose from, and give the appropriate user role(s) the "select different theme" permission.

Comment: Well, I am looking a way so that users (or even guests) can change the theme from front end.

Comment: OK, I see, my solution would not work for anonymous guest users. In that case, check out the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module as mentioned by Manu Benjamin, perhaps extended by the [Themekey Properties](http://drupal.org/project/themekey_properties) module. I've never used it but it looks as if you can switch themes based on session or cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module. After installing this module from 'ThemeKey User Profile' configuration, enable the option for user to select their own themes, so that it will be available in user profile and user can select their own themes.

Answer (score 1):

I am also convinced with [Switch Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/switchtheme) module. It provides a dropdown created in a block that provides option to choose any of the theme enabled from the backend.

So you just need to enable themes from backend that you want to show users to switch.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found [Switchtheme](https://www.drupal.org/project/switchtheme), which will give you a block that allows users to switch.